# IronPython and inheritance tree

Tags: inheritance, ironpython, typeerror

How does IronPython work with inheritance tree?

I have following problem. I've imported a class from .NET using clr.AddReference().
Than I want to pass an object to a method which waits for a specific type. But I have an object which is a subclass of the specific type and the method does not accept it.

Say I have a class A and subclass B of A. Than I pass isntance of B to method C who waits for A. In .NET is ok to pass subclasses, but IronPython throws a TypeError.

How can I make it clear to IronPython or cast B to A explicitly? 
clr.Convert does not help, it does not support cast to base class.

Specifically I want to run coded UI tests from IronPython. I was able to reference all needed libs and start tested app. Then I wanted to click on main window and here what I've got:

```
from System import *
from System.Threading import *
from System.Reflection import *
from Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting import *
from Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.WpfControls import *
import time

Playback.Initialize()
app = ApplicationUnderTest.Launch(r"application.exe")
try:
    main_window = WpfWindow()
    main_window.SearchProperties[WpfWindow.PropertyNames.Name] = "Application"

    Mouse.Click.Overloads[clr.GetClrType(UITestControl)](main_window)
finally:
    Playback.Cleanup()
```

When I run this code I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Tests.py", line 44, in <module>
TypeError: expected UITestControl, got WpfWindow
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: There is no reason this should not work. Could you provide more info? Small repro sample?

Comment: Hello! Thanks for response! I edited my question and added some examples.

Comment: And without explicit selection through overloads the call to `Mouse.Click` can't be resolved? [WpfWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.uitesting.wpfcontrols.wpfwindow.aspx) should be resolveable ..

Comment: I tried to give WpfWindow isntance to a method without explicit selection of overload, but in this case I've got the same error, but instead of UITestControl it was waiting for Point instance. I assume this is default overload.